# What to do to cool down oven after grease fire?

Tags: equipment, oven, temperature, fire

I have cleaned the grease out the oven but the oven is still warm and it’s not on. What do I do to get the oven to cool down so it’s back to normal?

Answer (score 6):

So long as the fire is truly out, then just give the oven time. It may take a few hours to cool the metal back to room-temperature, just as it would if you had baked something in it.

Answer (score 1):

You sure it's not on? Turn off the breaker to the stove and see if it cools. Possible the grease fire damaged the controls..